# Can't debug 32bit application with gdb and a dynamic loader into remote target arm64

Tags: c++, linux, arm, gdb, remote-debugging

I'm trying to use **gdb** for debug an application in an arm64 device in a particular situation:
-The device is an embedded linux arm64 running linux:

```
$ uname-a 
Linux HMI-fa93 4.14.78-rt47 #1 SMP PREEMPT RT Fri Apr 29 08:40:42 UTC 2022 aarch64 GNU/Linux
```

I have no problem at all when trying to use gdb with an application that uses native 64 bit (using gdb-multiarch on host and gdbserver aarch64 on target).

In this device i have also an application running at **32 bit** which is called using this command for execution:

```
/customfolder/lib32/ld-linux-armhf.so.3 --library-path /customfolder/lib32 ./TestGDB32
```

The application run whitout problems so far but the problem is when i want to debug it using gdb.

I've tested a lot of combinations but every time i'm not able to debug the application. I'm afraid that when launching the gdb he think that i'm trying to debug the ld-linux-armhf.so.3 and not my application.
I launch the debug in this way:

```
/customfolder/lib32/ld-linux-armhf.so.3 --library-path /customfolder/lib32 /customfolder/bin/gdbserver --once host:10010 /customfolder/lib32/ld-linux-armhf.so.3 --library-path /customfolder/lib32 ./TestGDB32
```

Basically i'm trying to run gdb at 32 bit and launching the debug of the 32 bit application.

The output on the host is like that:

```
0xf7fbea80 in ?? ()
(gdb) list
No symbol table is loaded.  Use the "file" command.
(gdb) bt
#0  0xf7fbea80 in ?? ()
#1  0x00000000 in ?? ()
Backtrace stopped: previous frame identical to this frame (corrupt stack?)
```

How can i debug an application at 32bit that runs with this dynamic loader using gdb?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I launch the debug in this way

Yes, when you launch the app this way, GDB will think that you are running `ld-linux-armhf.so.3`, and debugging will be very difficult.

It is *possible* to debug the app launched that way -- you would need to figure out where the main binary (assuming it's PIE) and all the shared libraries are loaded, and use `add-symbol-file` for each one, but a *much* easier solution is to simply build the application so it references desired loader (`-Wl,--dynamic-linker=/customfolder/lib32/ld-linux-armhf.so.3`) and has desired `RPATH` (`-rpath=/customfolder/lib32`), and launch it "normally" (`./TestGDB32`).

If you do that, debugging should just work™.